# Ansible - Looping over two lists

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

I've looked at similar questions and although I've solved the problem, I don't think it's the most elegant solution.

I'm trying to loop over a list of sites - which are individual dictionaries. For each site, I want to perform a series of replacements on a config file within the site using `lineinfile` (the path to the config file is determined from information in the sites dictionary)

I want to perform a loop over `lineinfile` with both these sites, and a list of regex/replacements to try. The only problem is, the list of replacements needs to use a value found within the sites dictionary.

I'm currently achieving this the following way, in `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Perform replacements with loop over sites
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: replacements.yml
  tags: test
  loop: "{{ sites }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: site
  vars:
    sites:
      - apache_servername: "site1.com"
        apache_documentroot: /var/www/site1
      - apache_servername: "site2.com"
        apache_documentroot: /var/www/site2
```

And the contents of `replacements.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Perform replacements
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: "{{ site.apache_documentroot }}/config.txt"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "{{ item.regex }}"
    state: present
    line: "{{ item.replacement }}"
  loop:
    - {regex: "(public \\$tmp_path.*?')(?:.+)(';)", replacement: "\\1{{ site.apache_documentroot }}/tmp\\2"}
    - {regex: "(public \\$log_path.*?')(?:.+)(';)", replacement: "\\1{{ site.apache_documentroot }}/administrator/logs\\2"}
    - {regex: "(public \\$password.*?')(?:.+)(';)", replacement: "\\1{{ site.password }}\\2"}
  tags: test
```

This works fine, but it is a little bit inelegant split out across multiple files, not to mention it's not the easiest to control those regex replacements - would be good if they could be held in a separate variable.

Is it possible to loop over these two lists of dictionaries together within the same task, whilst also allowing the regex replacements to reference a value of the first loop? I sort of imagine building a data structure that has all of these things created and then just looping over that.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate [*with_nested*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian). For example, simplified for the testing

```yaml
    - name: Perform replacements with loop over sites
      debug:
        msg: |
          path: {{ item.0.apache_documentroot }}/config.txt
          regexp: {{ item.1.regex }}
          line: {{ item.1.replace }}
      with_nested:
        - "{{ sites }}"
        - "{{ regex_replace }}"
      vars:
        sites:
          - apache_servername: site1.com
            apache_documentroot: /var/www/site1
          - apache_servername: site2.com
            apache_documentroot: /var/www/site2
        regex_replace:
          - {regex: A, replace: X}
          - {regex: B, replace: Y}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    path: /var/www/site1/config.txt
    regexp: A
    line: X
--
  msg: |-
    path: /var/www/site1/config.txt
    regexp: B
    line: Y
--
  msg: |-
    path: /var/www/site2/config.txt
    regexp: A
    line: X
--
  msg: |-
    path: /var/www/site2/config.txt
    regexp: B
    line: Y
```